# Limit sending messages to SQS based on the content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

Using IAM policies, is it possible to prevent users from sending SQS messages containing certain attribute?

For example, I'd like to allow IAM user "U1" to send only messages having attribute "City" set to either "Rome" or "Paris". Providing any other city should raise an error.

Creating one queue for each city is not a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that sort of functionality is not supported by SQS

If you want such a functionality you can add a layer of AWS API gateway and AWS Lambda before your SQS and ask your users to invoke the API Gateway endpoint. Then from API gateway this request goes to Lambda where you can perform the checks and validations and then if all OK , insert the message to SQS or else give back an error

If you want to manage it all using IAM you can replace API Gateway with S3 and cause lambda to be invoked via S3 Put notification. You can create folders in S3 and set IAM access on those. For more details refer [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Unfortunately, the problem is still there: how do I regulate what users can do using only IAM policies? I'd like to avoid having a database that regulates the access.